# How to keep a Bootstrap Dropdown Checkbox list down dropped down

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using a pretty cool [Bootstrap Dropdown-checkbox](http://acquisio.github.io/bootstrap-dropdown-checkbox/#), but it has a button above the list to drop down the list, and I would like to keep the list dropped down. It compares favourably with other CheckBoxList controls I have seen.

The HTML it renders is basically, with the list hidden:

```
<div id="agency-suburbs-list" class="suburbDropdownCheckbox dropdown-checkbox dropdown">
    <button class="dropdown-checkbox-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false">Suburbs List</button>
    <div class="dropdown-checkbox-content">
        <ul class="dropdown-checkbox-menu">
            <li>
                <div class="layout">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="247908647965.94836"><label for="247908647965.94836">Alberante</label>
                </div>
            </li>
            ...
            <li>
                <div class="layout">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="882857971221.6206"><label for="882857971221.6206">Alrode</label>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comparing that HTML to what is rendered when it is dropped down, the sole difference is the the very outer `div` has an extra class of `open`. The API shown on the control's web page shows no JS function to open or close it, and me applying the class manually doesn't open the dropdown;

```
$("#me-open").click(function(e) {
        $("#agency-suburbs-list").addClass("open");
    });
```

Where `me-open` is just an extra button independent of the control I added for testing. Everything else about this control seems to work perfectly, so I would like to keep it, the list is supposed to populate when the user selects a value from a `select`, and then also having to click another button to see the selected values is quite a bad UX factor.

Answer (score 0):

That dropdown checkbox is a bootstrap modal. It triggers to be shown when the button is pushed.

If you want to always display it you need to add some css like so:

```
.dropdown-checkbox-content {
    display: block!important; /* or inline-block */
    position: static!important;
}
```

If you want to hide the toggle button:

```
dropdown-checkbox-toggle {
    display: none;
}
```